# Credentials for SES using AWS SDK PHP (SMTP/IAM)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

I am new to the world of AWS and I'm not someone who comes from a security background so the concepts surrounding AWS IAM and the SMTP settings have my head spinning.

I've installed the AWS PHP SDK by following all the steps, verified the domain (as well as successfully sending a few test emails from the AWS console) and also a few individual email addresses that I want to send the test emails to, but the part I don't get is the SMTP/IAM.

I've got Amazon's basic script that they provide, but I don't really understand what I need to do in creating the SMTP credentials and/or IAM and I've searched all over without being able to really find an answer or understand what the Amazon docs are saying.

The code I am using is below, but the part I am totally bewildered by is exactly how I should generate my access keys for this specific item (I only need to send emails, no handling of bounces, etc) and what the best method of accessing these from the script are (i.e. I assume they should be stored outside of the actual script in a locked down directory?).

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = SesClient::factory(array(
    'key' => 'SECRET_KEY',
    'secret' => 'SECRET_SECRET',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1',
    'version' => '2010-12-01'
));

$emailSentId = $client->sendEmail(array(
    // Source is required
    'Source' => 'donotreply@mydomain.com',
    // Destination is required
    'Destination' => array(
        'ToAddresses' => array('sendto@mydomain.com')
    ),
    // Message is required
    'Message' => array(
        // Subject is required
        'Subject' => array(
            // Data is required
            'Data' => 'SES Testing',
            'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
        ),
        // Body is required
        'Body' => array(
            'Text' => array(
                // Data is required
                'Data' => 'My plain text email',
                'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
            ),
            'Html' => array(
                // Data is required
                'Data' => '<b>My HTML Email</b>',
                'Charset' => 'UTF-8',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'ReplyToAddresses' => array( 'donotreply@mydomain.com' ),
    'ReturnPath' => 'donotreply@mydomain.com'
));




?>
```

I tried going into the SES console and generating SMTP keys there and plugging them straight into the script (just to test if it would work, I've removed them from the script and deleted those keys for security purposes), but I didn't really understand if I should be using them or if I then need to create an additional IAM user or if I should be generating these dynamic combinations that have been referred to (happy to take expert advice on this for the bets method) ... in any that threw me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Exception\CredentialsException' with message 'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (Client error: `GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:  Aws\Credentials{closure}(Array) #1 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(152): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(2, Array, Array) #2 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(60): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}() #3 /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlMultiHandler.php(96): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run() #4 /var/www in /var/www/html/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/Credentials/InstanceProfileProvider.php on line 79

Anyway, hopefully someone understands what I am rambling about - happy to provide any additional details, but I don't think I'm adding much value to the issue from here on as I'm sure comes through from this question, I don't really understand the security side of it.

It will truly be a Christmas miracle if I can get this working, understand the basic concepts and still have some hair left by the time the last mince pie goes down my throat.

Thanks in advance!!

G-Man

Answer (score 11):

If anyone runs into the same problem, to get mine working after finding a clue here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/configuration.html), I did the following:

1. Verify emails/domains
2. Created an IAM user with AmazonSESFullAccess (amend as necessary)
3. Plugged the keys into the script above in the sections:

   ```
   'key' => 'SECRET_KEY',
   'secret' => 'SECRET_SECRET',
   ```
4. However, this failed with the same error when I ran it.
5. Changing the above to the following however, ran successfully and sent the email ...

   ```
   'credentials' => [
   'key'    => 'SECRET_KEY',
   'secret' => 'SECRET_SECRET'],
   ```

Hopefully someone finds this useful.

Cheers!!

Comment: Nice coding. I'm following your script. I've installed the AWS PHP SDK. Do we need to set SMTP Host & SMTP Port to enable SMTP?

Comment: You just need step 5, step 2 isn't necessary

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to uses AWS SES. One is to use the SMTP interfce, and the other is to use the SES API directly.

When using SES SMTP, generating the SMTP keys they way you did is the proper way, and imo, the easiest way if all you want to do is send out some emails. If you have ever used any other SMTP server to send emails from your application, then the SES-SMTP interface is a drop-in replacement - no code changes would be required, you just generated the credentials and use them.

On the other hand, if you are using the SES API directly, then you would use regular IAM credentials instead.

> **Using Credentials With Amazon SES**
>
> To interact with Amazon Simple Email Service (Amazon SES), you use security credentials to verify who
>   you are and whether you have permission to interact with Amazon SES.
>   There are different types of credentials, and the credentials you use
>   depend on what you want to do. For example, you use AWS access keys
>   when you send an email using the Amazon SES API, and SMTP credentials
>   when you send an email using the Amazon SES SMTP interface.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-credentials.html

Comment: Thanks EJB ... I was totally with you on the two different methods, but it appears there was a slight issue in the AWS code, which I will post as an additional answer below ... it seems your answer has solved somebody else's problem though - thanks for the input!!!